# Intel Edison: C++ files using MRAA::UART don't compile

Tags: c++, cmake, debian, intel-edison

I'm using an Intel Edison running Debian. I need to use mraa::uart in a C++ program, but g++ can't find the functions I use. These are the steps I followed to install MRAA:

```
mkdir mraa/build && cd $_
cmake .. -DBUILDSWIGNODE=OFF
make
make install
```

The cmake step had some errors and there was no makefile for the make step, but other C++ programs using mraa (gpio specifically) work. I tried installing cmake-3.2.2, but when following directions I got installation errors that I couldn't figure out. I don't think cmake is the issue though, because another Edison we're using worked fine with the same version of cmake.

Comment: `The cmake step had some errors and there was no makefile for the make step` - this normaly signals about some some problems. Show these errors. `but g++ can't find the functions I use.` - this problem description is too vague. Show the code and errors, which are generated when you compile it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled cmake-3.2.2 twice. It eventually worked. Not sure how the other Edison worked without 3.2.2 or why the third attempt at installing cmake-3.2.2 worked. Once I got this working, I had to move the library files to my lib folder before things would compile